# VS code doesnot display some UTF-8 characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code does not display some UTF-8 characters like '⦃' and '⟪'.

The VS code is running on Windows 10 Pro and other editors, notepad and Visual Studio 2015 Community Editor, can display that UTF-8 characters.

What settings for VS code are need to display the characters?

Comment: I can reproduce, can you file an issue for this at our GH repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: @BenjaminPasero Thank you for your advice. I filed an issue for this.